# how to generate jp2k distorted images with differnt compression ratios in python

Tags: python, jpeg2000

I am working with glymur package right now. is there any method that i can control the generated image with different compression ratio?

```
im=Image.open("F:/t.bmp")
jp2=glymur.Jp2k("F:/distortion_images/2.jp2",data=array(im),numres=())
x=glymur.Jp2k("F:/distortion_images/2.jp2")
img=Image.fromarray(x[:])
img.show()
```

i think i need to add some parameters at the back of `numres`, but it turned out the same image, maybe my `numres` is not valid.
Can anyone help with this or applying other methods?